# Cannot SELECT from MYSQL database

Tags: php, mysql

I have a mysql database in which I am administering via phpMyAdmin.

I can run `INSERT` and `CREATE` just fine with php, but cannot  `SELECT` data from my database.

However, when I `SELECT` inside of phpMyAdmin it works just fine.

---

I get no errors, but the browser outputs a status of:

> 500 (Internal Server Error)

---

```
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

$sql = "SELECT * FROM test";

$result = $conn->query($sql);
echo mysql_error(); die;

echo "$result";

$conn->close();
```

Comment: Did you check the error logs? Both the web server and mysql

Comment: I think u cannot echo $result directly

Comment: yes, @jophab is right. you cannot echo `$result` directly. if you want to get the result then try something like this `list($field) = $result->fetch_row();`

Comment: wont matter he kills the script before that point with `die`

Comment: yeah. He already kill the script before even trying to output the `$result`. The right approach would be something like `if($result){ list($field) = $result->fetch_row(); }else{die(mysql_error());}`

Comment: You can't echo the result this way. Did you check your query in phpmyadmin.??

Comment: I think you first you should read about execution of database query via PHP.

Comment: [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_select.asp) try this its also in mysqli

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For successful `SELECT` query `mysqli_query()` will return a `mysqli_result object`.

ie, `$result` is a `mysqli_result object`.
So you cannot echo it directly.

Use `mysqli_fetch-assoc()` to get an associative array of strings representing the fetched row in the result set.

**Also you are mixing mysqli and mysql functions**

Use `mysqli_error()` function.

Comment: that wont cause "500 (Internal Server Error)"

Comment: @Dagon I think it is. I dont see any chance for other reasons in this small code. Are u sure?

Comment: @jophab Yes it is